# Filter Condition mandatory and non-mandatory using and/or clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the Following Table1

```
Brand Payment_method
Soap  Cash
Soap  Card
Juice  Cash
pen    Card
```

Brand is a mandatory prompt and Payment_method is non mandatory prompt

**Requirement:**

if i provide value to Brand like soap and no value to payment_method.then it should display like below

```
brand   payment_method
soap     Cash
soap      Card
```

if i provide value for brand like soap and value for payment_method as Cash.then it should provide the below output

```
brand   payment_method
soap     Cash
```

**Used Codes:**

Code 1: if use the below code

```
select * from table1 where Brand=:brand and payment_method=:PM
```

where :brand = 'Soap' and :PM =''

it should show value for brand='Soap'..but due to and condition and :PM is Blank it showing no record

Code 2 :if i use below or condition

```
select * from table1 where where :brand = 'Soap' or :PM ='card'
```

it should show value for :brand='Soap' and :PM = 'card' but it showing below records.pen brand is getting included

```
brand payment_method
Soap  Card
pen   Card
```

any way to achieve the requirement using SQL.please help me

Comment: The output from your query is correct.  What did you intend it to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have change the Scenario.please Help me .

Comment: I can't help you because you never showed us the output you want.  Your queries are running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM suppliers 
WHERE (state = 'California' AND supplier_id <> 900) OR (supplier_id = '');
```

here it `(supplier_id = '')`  returns nothing so you got only California.

But

```
SELECT * 
FROM suppliers 
WHERE (state = 'California' AND supplier_id <> 900) OR (supplier_id = 100);
```

this `(supplier_id = 100)` matched the Washington as its supplier_id  is 100.

Also those are in OR condition that is the reason for getting Washington  in the above query

**Example**

```
A or '' = A

A or B = AB
```

to get the expected result

```
SELECT * 
FROM suppliers 
WHERE (state = 'California') AND ((supplier_id <> 900) OR (supplier_id = 100))
```

Comment: Hi @EswarVignesh, Are you using any Programing language to communicate and execute this select query ? like C# or Java ?

Comment: If so, Then you have to handle it in the application level.

Comment: Am using the Query in BI publisher